# symfony4 Could not open input file: bin/symfony_requirements

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I'm deploying a Symfony4 project with these instructions:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/deployment.html#common-post-deployment-tasks

Says that:

> A. Check Requirements
>
> Check if your server meets the requirements by running:
>
> **$ php bin/symfony_requirements**

And it doesn't work.

```
$ php bin/symfony_requirements
Could not open input file: bin/symfony_requirements
```

Does it have to be done differently with app/console?

Comment: For Symfony 4 you actually need to install the requirements checker: [composer require requirements-checker](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should read this documentation; https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/requirements.html

```
cd your-project/
composer require requirements-checker
```

Checking Requirements for the Command Console

The requirements checker tool adds a script to your Composer configuration to check the requirements automatically. There's no need to execute any command; if there is any issue, you'll see them in the console output.